# Moving elements between 2 boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have looked through same questions on this topic but somehow suggested solutions do not work for me :/

Problem is that divs get moved from #box1 to #box2 only once. If detach() used then divs are clickable in #box2 but get rearranged when clicked. If remove()used divs are not clickable in #box2 at all (event listener gone?). I have a feeling that the process of moving the divs is somehow not really complete and I ether have duplicates around in DOM or moved divs disappear entirely and do not react to clicks.

I tried detach(), remove() and appendTo() in various combinations and the best I can get is in the fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/uoz3t914/13/

```
$('#box1 .item' ).on('click', function() {
 // $( this ).detach().appendTo('#box2'); moves divs around in #box2
 $( this ).remove().appendTo('#box2');
});

$('#box2 .item' ).on('click', function() {
 // $( this ).detach().appendTo('#box2'); moves divs around in #box2
 $( this ).appendTo('#box1');
});
```

Comment: Problem is that divs get moved from #box1 to #box2 only once. I cannot move them out of #box2 back to #box1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you have  to use the [Event Delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#box1' ).off().on('click','.item', function() {
     // $( this ).detach().appendTo('#box2'); moves divs around in #box2
     $( this ).appendTo('#box2');
});

$('#box2' ).off().on('click', '.item', function() {
     // $( this ).detach().appendTo('#box2'); moves divs around in #box2
     $( this ).appendTo('#box1');
});
```

You attach the event to the parent, that propagate it to the children, and then any time that you attach the event, put an `off()` to detach it.

```js
$('#box1' ).off().on('click','.item', function() {
     // $( this ).detach().appendTo('#box2'); moves divs around in #box2
     $( this ).appendTo('#box2');
});

$('#box2' ).off().on('click', '.item', function() {
     // $( this ).detach().appendTo('#box2'); moves divs around in #box2
     $( this ).appendTo('#box1');
});
```

```css
.item {
 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

#box1 {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

#i1 {
     background-color: yellow;     
}

#i2 {
    background-color: green;
       
}

#i3 {
    background-color: red;  
    
}

#box2{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="box1">
    <div class ="item" id ="i1"></div>
    <div class ="item" id ="i2"></div>
    <div class ="item" id ="i3"></div>
</div>

<div id = "box2">
    
</div>
```

Comment: +1. This is the correct solution, because the `click` event in OP's code is only bound to pre-existing elements. Once they are moved to a new box, that binding is lost. By listening to the event bubbling up to the parent container would be the best solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You can move them between the boxes with:

```
$('#box1, #box2').on('click', '.item', function () {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().prop('id') == 'box1' ? '#box2' : '#box1');
});
```

```js
$('#box1, #box2').on('click', '.item', function () {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().prop('id') == 'box1' ? '#box2' : '#box1');
});
```

```css
.item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#box1 {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
#i1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#i2 {
    background-color: green;
}
#i3 {
    background-color: red;
}
#box2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1">
    <div class="item" id="i1"></div>
    <div class="item" id="i2"></div>
    <div class="item" id="i3"></div>
</div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

This uses `.on()`'s event delegation syntax to handle the elements, and a ternary operator to determine which box the element exists in.

Comment: good answer! But it's exactly the same logic of my answer, what did you change? The ternary operator? Not fair!

Answer (score 1):

Use this html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id ="box1" class="container">
        <div class ="item" id ="i1"></div>
        <div class ="item" id ="i2"></div>
        <div class ="item" id ="i3"></div>
    </div>

    <div id = "box2" class="container">

    </div>
</div>
```

and this javascript

```
$('.item').on('click', function(){
    var index = $("#wrapper > .container").index($(this).parent()),
        maxIndex = $('#wrapper > .container').length,
        nextIndex = (index + 1) < maxIndex ? (index + 1) : 0;

    $(this).appendTo($('#wrapper > .container').eq(nextIndex));
});
```

in your fiddle to move boxes between any number of containers

You may also add Box3, Box4 (with class .container) etc. into the "#wrapper div", you may do it dynamycally

Comment: Thanx! What does ">" do?

Comment: ">" take the direct children